# Boost Python callback returning auto_ptr deletes the object

Tags: c++, boost-python, auto-ptr

I'm creating bindings for a 3rd party library that takes ownership of objects so I'm trying to use auto_ptr as documented in the [FAQ](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/python/doc/v2/faq.html#ownership).

Here's an example of two classes I've wrapped:

```
typedef std::auto_ptr<Panel> PanelAutoPtr;

class NewPanelCallback {
public:
    NewPanelCallback(object c) { callable = c; }
    PanelAutoPtr operator() (wxWindow* parent) {
        object result = callable(boost::ref(parent));
        return extract<PanelAutoPtr>(result);
    }
private:
    object callable;
};

void Factory_register_method(Factory* f,
                             const wxString& id,
                             boost::python::object callable)
{
    f->registerFactoryMethod(id, NewPanelCallback(callable));
}

class_<Factory, boost::noncopyable>("Factory", no_init)
    .def("get", &Factory::get, return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>());
    .def("register", &Factory_register_method);

class_<Panel, std::auto_ptr<Panel>, bases<wxWindow>, boost::noncopyable)
    ("Panel", init<wxWindow*, int, const wxString&>()>;
```

My application allows plugin developers to register Python function as factory methods for creating widgets. An example:

```
class MyPanel(shell.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, name):
        super().__init__(parent, id, name)

def create_panel(parent):
    return MyPanel(parent, -1, "Test")

shell.Factory.get().register("some_panel", create_panel)
```

Now, my problem is that when my program calls the NewPanelCallback functor (in C++) the panel object is deleted before the call operator returns! It's like the extract function call does not take ownership of the pointer from the result object as it should.

```
void create_a_panel(wxFrame* frm, NewPanelCallback& cb) {
    PanelAutoPtr p = cb(frm);
    frm->Add(p.get());
    p.release();
}
```

Any hints?

### Solution

I finally fixed this by not using "extract". This is my new NewPanelCallback():

```
class NewPanelItemCallback {
public:
    NewPanelItemCallback(object c) { callable = c; }
    PanelAutoPtr operator() (wxWindow* parent) {
        return call<Shell::PanelAutoPtr>(callable.ptr(), boost::ref(parent));
    }
private:
    object callable;
};
```

I'm not really sure why this works and the other way doesn't. Any comments on that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. I've edited the question to include the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use auto_ptr - it's evil and deprecated.  Replace it with unique_ptr, or shared_ptr.  Specifically, auto_ptr is much more eager to delete its payload by inadvertently transferring ownership to temps, because it lacks the r-value copy and move semantics that unique_ptr and shared_ptr now have.

Comment: Very valid comment but doesn’t actually answer the question.

Comment: In this case I think it's the correct pointer type to use. The 3rd party library takes ownership of the objects so shared_ptr can't be used (the library does not use shared_ptrs). I'm not sure if using unique_ptr would help me. See the link to the FAQ I posted above.

Comment: Without all the source, it's hard to tell where the eager delete is occurring, but I'd look at your extract<> template, which appears to be some kind of container.  This is one of specific problem areas for auto_ptr, and why it's deprecated in favor of unique_ptr.  See Herb Sutter's article - http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/025.htm.

Comment: The extract template is part of boost::python: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/python/doc/v2/extract.html. Since the FAQ of boost::python recommends using auto_ptr I'd guess it can handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Boost supports `movable` semantics and `unique_ptr` [since v.1.55](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_55_0.html).
But in my project I used previous version and made such simple wrapper:

```
class_<unique_ptr<HierarchyT>, noncopyable>(typpedName<LinksT>("hierarchy", false)
, "hierarchy holder")
    .def("__call__", &unique_ptr<HierarchyT>::get,
        return_internal_reference<>(),
        "get holding hierarchy")
    .def("reset", &unique_ptr<HierarchyT>::reset,
        "reset holding hierarhy")
    ;
```

to create `unique_ptr<HierarchyT>` and pass it to the function that accepts it by reference. Python code:

```
hier = mc.shierarchy()
mc.clusterize(hier, nds)
```

where C++ function is `float clusterize(unique_ptr<HierarchyT>& hier,...)`.
Then to access results in Python: `output(hier(), nds)`.
Keep it simple :-)